# Can't set maxFilesize in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I have been trying in vain to set maxFilesize in dropzone.js. Although I set it at 1MB, I can still upload files larger than that. Here is the JS:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: '.stl, .pac'
 }
```

And here is the form:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
```

Maybe it is worth noting that the acceptedFiles directive works. Also the upload_max_filesize in php is set at 2M.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you inserted `<script src="../some/place/js/vendor/dropzone.js" />` before or after declaring options?

Comment: I added it before.